Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components
I'm getting this error when I'm trying to pass data from Client side to Server side in NextJs
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.
Client Side Code
const form = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      student_fname: "",
      student_lname: "",
      student_birth: "",
      student_bplace: "",
      student_phone: "",
      student_gender: "", // Add "student_gender" as a valid argument
    },
  });

  async function onSubmit() {
    //temp
    const supabase =await  createServerObject();
    await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email: 'admin@email.com',
      password: '12345678',
    });
    let mapData = new Map(Object.entries(form.getValues()));
    // var user_id = (await supabase.auth.getUser()).data.user?.id;
    var user_id = "1";
    console.log(user_id);
    const errMsg = await createStudent(JSON.stringify(mapData),user_id.toString());
    if(JSON.parse(errMsg)!=""){
      alert("ERROR : "+errMsg);
      return;
    }
    alert("Student Inserted");
}

Server Side Code
export async function createStudent(formData: any, user_id: string = ""): Promise<string> {
    try {
        formData = JSON.parse(formData);
        console.log(formData);
        const supabase = await createServerObject(); // Create Supabase client
        // Check if user is an admin
        const { data: adminData, error: adminError } = await supabase
            .from("admin")
            .select("*")
            .eq("user_id", user_id);

        if (adminError) {
            console.log(adminError);
            throw adminError;
        }

        if (adminData && adminData.length > 0) {
            const adminSupaClient = await createSupbaseAdmin(); // Create Admin Supabase client
            const userResponse = adminSupaClient.auth.getUser();
            const createResult = await adminSupaClient.auth.admin.createUser({
                email: formData.email,
                password: formData.password,
                user_metadata: {
                    role: 'student',
                }
            });
            console.log("STEP 3");

            if (createResult.error?.message) {
                console.log("STEP ERROR");
                return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createResult));

            }

            const response = await adminSupaClient.from("student").insert({
                user_id: (await userResponse).data.user?.id,
                student_fname: formData.student_fname,
                student_lname: formData.student_lname,
                student_birth: formData.student_birth,
                student_bplace: formData.student_bplace,
                student_gender: formData.student_gender
            });
            console.log("Student inserted");
            if (response.error) {
                console.log(response.error); throw response.error;
            }

            console.log("STEP 4 : SUCCESS");
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(""));
        } else {
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("User is not an admin"));
        }


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}

Error details :
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.

Call Stack
<unknown>
file:///H:/Work/SchoolGate/schoolgateweb/schoolgate_web/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:277727)
Object.toJSON
file:///H:/Work/SchoolGate/schoolgateweb/schoolgate_web/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:280578)
stringify
<anonymous>
<unknown>
file:///H:/Work/SchoolGate/schoolgateweb/schoolgate_web/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:266934)
eW
file:///H:/Work/SchoolGate/schoolgateweb/schoolgate_web/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:267013)
ez
file:///H:/Work/SchoolGate/schoolgateweb/schoolgate_web/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:267413)
Timeout._onTimeout
file:///H:/Work/SchoolGate/schoolgateweb/schoolgate_web/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:263912)
listOnTimeout
node:internal/timers (573:17)
process.processTimers
node:internal/timers (514:7)

I have tried to use JSON.stringify("") but have not worked for me

Why do you JSON.stringify() your server action calls? NextJS already does the serialisation for you.

In this I agree but it is not the problem.
the problem was not on my code it was on supabase package they migrated to SSR
in the last month which i was getting exception when using temp authentification on client side.

I was able to solve it by moving everything to server side while passing the form data from client side
